# How should I install packages that generally are available in Ubuntu repos on Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have Linux Mint in my home computer and I'm about to install Debian Jessie in my work computer. I have dealt with Debian before and many packages that are available in Ubuntu repositories by default aren't available for Debian. As someone who needs all those packages I was wondering what would be the correct way of installing them on Debian.

The first thought that came to me was adding Ubuntu sources to `sources.list`, but I read [some things](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251239/add-ubuntu-repository-to-debian) and apparently people do not recommend this.

Since I have to install many of these packages, I also would like to avoid having to install them from source one-by-one.

What would be the preferred way to do this task?

Thank you.

Comment: Are they available on Debian repos ?

Comment: The right way would be to use `Ubuntu` in that case. However, the vast majority of packages from Ubuntu should be available for Debian as well, since Ubuntu is based on Debian. If you are talking about PPAs, then use Ubuntu!

Comment: They are not available on Debian and (forgive my lack of knowledge) I'm not sure they are PPAs or not. Some example of things I've tried to install are `ipython`, `python-pandas`, `redshift`. I'll do some further reading on PPAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm  don't think you can install them from the repos if you don't want to add sources in sources.list.

If we are talking about reasonably small number of packages (say 10) I would recommend checking if .deb packages exist on the home pages.

For example: 
http://pkgs.org/download/ipython

This is much easier than installing from source. It's not fully automated solution, but for smaller number of packages you can do it.

I hope it helps.